# Would adding a Mac mini to my MacBook Pro set up help with processing bandwidth?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mac-mini

I have a MacBook Pro 16” Intel variety that I got from work. I use two 32” monitors and the screen on the laptop. I recently added a RØDECaster Pro audio interface and a Blackmagic Design ATEM Mini Pro. It seems that I have hit the limit of what this laptop can do all at the same time.

Could I add an M1 Mac mini to use with the MacBook Pro and split the processing power and RAM of both to bear the load? Any advice on if and then how would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what processing tasks you are doing? Some kind of video stuff? What software? What resolution are the displays? What makes you think that you have 'hit the limit'?

Answer (score 1):

It is not generally possible to combine two computers (doesn't matter if it is Macs or PCs) to increase performance of whatever programs you're running.

Combining multiple computers to increase performance requires specialized software that is completely dependent on the task, you're trying to perform.

In some cases you can do it simply by dividing work items. I.e. use the MacBook Pro to send its video output to your BlackMagic Design ATEM Mini Pro, and use the Mac Mini to record audio from the RØDECaster Pro audio interface.

However, in many cases you want to use all the peripherals as if it is a single computer. I.e. for example recording a video from the BlackMagic Design ATEM Mini Pro while at the same time recording the audio from the RØDECaster Pro audio interface into the same program. It's not possible to just combine two computers to do that - unless you have some very specialized software to perform that task.